# importing fiona before shapely raising geos-related OSError

Tags: shapely, fiona

I ran into an issue where the order of imports for fiona and shapely caused the following geos error below which happens when i import `fiona` before `shapely`.  **If I do the reverse all is fine.**  Must be something screwy on my system.  Any tips?

```
>>> import fiona
>>> from shapely.geometry import shape

OSError: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants ['/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/Current/GEOS', '/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'].
```

`shapely.__version__ == 1.5.13`

`fiona.__version__ == 1.5.1`

platform OSX

Comment: I can confirm that this happens for me too, since migrating to EL Capitain. I am using Anaconda for Python. Unable to post comments, so putting this here.

Comment: This is likely a subtlety to do with how Fiona and Shapely locate your geos. Do you know if you have different versions of geos on your system?  And do you know which one of these has precedence in your system path variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem between ctypes (the Python ffi module) and GEOS shared libs on OS X such that the state of the GEOS lib is corrupted when you load it again via `import shapely`. It's not a problem on Linux, as far as I can tell.

The [Fiona wheels for macosx and Python 2.7, 3.4, and 3.5 on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona#downloads) have statically linked GEOS libraries and won't interfere with Shapely. I recommend using them instead of Anaconda distributions until this bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Platform OS X 10.11 El whatever
         ,python 2.7.11
         ,shapely 1.5.16

I had a similar problem when I import geo-related package inside python.

```
    from shapely.geometry import shape, MultiPolygon
```

and I had such a thing

```
    Failed `CDLL(/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib)`
```

I search a lot on Google. But for me, the problem just ends with doing this

```
    pip install geos
```

I just need to manually install geos and that's fine

OS I also do this:

```
    sudo mkdir opt
```

to create a folder named opt under / 
But I am not sure if this helps. Just to let you know if manually installing geos still does not help you.